# Golang JWT is invalid with go-jwt-middleware

Tags: go, jwt

Got `JWT is invalid` with new version of `"github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/v2"`

successfully generate token with `"github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4"` plugin, and try to use it on request but rejected on middleware, i guess the issues in `go-jwt-middleware`. there is some missing with implementation, maybe anyone has already implement and want to share please

Here is the code:

```
type Claims struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Role     string `json:"role"`
    Id       string `json:"id"`
    Avatar   string `json:"avatar"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}

func (c *Claims) Validate(ctx context.Context) error {
    return nil
}

var jwtKey = []byte("secret")

func Middleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    keyFunc := func(ctx context.Context) (interface{}, error) {
        return jwtKey, nil
    }

    customClaims := func() validator.CustomClaims {
        return &Claims{}
    }

    jwtValidator, err := validator.New(
        keyFunc,
        validator.HS256,
        "issuer",
        []string{"audience"},
        validator.WithCustomClaims(customClaims),
        validator.WithAllowedClockSkew(30*time.Second),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to set up the validator: %v", err)
    }

    // Set up the middleware.
    middleware := jwtmiddleware.New(jwtValidator.ValidateToken)
    return middleware.CheckJWT(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, token, err := ParseToken(r)
        if !token.Valid || err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(401)
            w.Write([]byte("Unauthorized"))
            return
        }

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }))
}

func GenerateToken(id string, username string, role string, avatar string) (string, int64, error) {
    expirationTime := time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix()
    claims := &Claims{
        Id:       id,
        Username: username,
        Role:     role,
        Avatar:   avatar,
        StandardClaims: jwt.StandardClaims{
            ExpiresAt: expirationTime,
        },
    }

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, claims)
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString(jwtKey)
    if err != nil {
        return "", 0, err
    }

    return tokenString, expirationTime, nil
}
```

And i don't found any doccumentation for the value for `issuer` && `audience` option on validator. just follow the [example](https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware/blob/master/examples/http-example/main.go):

```
    jwtValidator, err := validator.New(
        keyFunc,
        validator.HS256,
        "issuer", <------------ issuer
        []string{"audience"}, <------------ audience
        validator.WithCustomClaims(customClaims),
        validator.WithAllowedClockSkew(30*time.Second),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Issuer:   issuerURL,
        Audience: audience,
```

The audience value is a string -- typically, the base address of the resource being accessed. for example which services, APIs, products should accept this token as an access token for the service. A token valid for Stackoveflow should not be accepted for the Stack exchange website, even if both of them have the same issuer, they’ll have different audiences.

Issuer value is a string like this `https://<issuer-url>/` Who created the token. like token issued by GitHub or LinkedIn and this can be verified by using the OpenID configuration endpoint

Comment: understood, thanks for explaining 

Comment: @DarmawanZ. is this resolved? I got same problem. Token is generated using same algorithm on different service in java but receiving the token in new service in golang using the above code is always returning 401.

Comment: I guess it's different Issue. I decide to not set issuer and audience.

But on your case, maybe you need to check the secret while claims the token. Make sure u use the same secret where you generated the token